# How to switch Tab and pass Data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

My Component structure

customer - material tab

- contains Tab1 - customer table view
- contains Tab2 - edit customer view

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="View">
    <div>
      <app-customer-table></app-customer-table>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Edit">
    <div>
      <app-customer-create></app-customer-create>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


When I click on an "edit" icon, that is inside Tab1, I want to switch to Tab2 and pass my "customer:CustomerDTO" to it.

How can I achieve this?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Output in the first component --> store value in a variable
You can use @Input in the second component and pass the above variable

Code looks like below:

```
 <mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="View">
    <div>
      <app-customer-table (onClickEdit)="edit($event)"></app-customer-table>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Edit">
    <div>
      <app-customer-create [customerId]="customerId"></app-customer-create>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

// main-componet.ts file

edit(value)=>{
this.customerId = value;
}

// customer-create.component.ts

@Input CustomerId;

// customer-table.component.ts
@Output onClickEdit = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Comment: ok I think I understand this, but how to switch the mat-tab on click "edit"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in a few steps:

1. Create a service using this command:

```
ng generate service data-passing
```

2. Define two variables in that service that holds your data for each component:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataPassingService {
  public firstTabData;
  public secondTabData;

  constructor() { }

}
```

3. Use service in your component:

```
import {DataPassingService} from '...';

...
constructor(public dataPassingService: DataPassingService) {
}
```

4. Store each component data in relative variable:

```
setDate(first, second) {
  this.dataPassingService.firstTabData = first;
  this.dataPassingService.secondTabData = second;
}
```

5. Use each data you want in tabs

> you can also define a `data` variable and store data there instead of two variables

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to the component, you can either use a service or use property binding and event binding syntaxes like this:

Inside tab1, use an `EventEmitter`. Once the user clicks edit invoke the `emit` function and pass the required data.
Using event binding, retrieve the data in the parent component and pass it to the child component by property binding.

Check here: https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

To switch tab, inject the `<mat-tab-group>` in component.ts using `@ViewChild` decorator and change the `selectedIndex` property of it.

Comment: you mean like this ´´´   @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) matTabGroup: MatTabGroup | undefined; ```

Comment: yes. Then on your edit function (in parent), invoke this.matTabGroup.selectedIndex = 1